# A participle phrase or An adjective phrase?

Tags: adjective-phrases, participle-phrases

"You could find yourself blowing up at the smallest things, doing or saying things in the heat of the moment that you later regret."

Let "doing or saying things in the heat of the moment that you later regret." x

In this sentense, Is x a participle phrase, so blowing up and doing or saying happen simultaneously?

or

Is x an adjective phrase, so you could find yourself in both situatuons?

Comment: I believe you forgot the "be" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "doing or saying things in the heat of the moment that you later regret." is a non-finite participle clause, it is headed by the compounded verbs "doing or saying",  these are "-ing" verbs, or gerund/participles.

As far as I can tell, there are no adjectives at all in this sentence.

The participle phrase ""doing or saying things..." is in a parallel construction with "blowing up ..."  So the structure is

```
You could find yourself ¬
                         - blowing up....
                         - doing or saying ...
```

The predictable repeatable part "You could find yourself"  is omitted.